# Scraping job hunting website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape all the **complete job descriptions** from this website but I got stuck:
https://www.seek.co.nz/data-analyst-jobs/full-time?daterange=31&salaryrange=70000-999999&salarytype=annual

My logic is to find all the job links on one page first than loop through next pages.

My code looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
link_list = []

for a in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'data-automation': 'jobTitle'}, href=True):
    link_list.append('https://www.seek.co.nz/' + a['href'])
print(link_list)
```

The above code looks fine. I can print a list of job links and put them in a list, but the following code only printed out 2 paragraphs then it threw an error:

```
for link in link_list:
    response = requests.get(link, 'lxml')
    sp = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    table = sp.find_all('div',attrs={'data-automation': 'jobDescription'})
    for x in table:
        print(x.find('p').text)
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-8afe949a9497> in <module>()
      4     table = sp.find_all('div',attrs={'data-automation': 'jobDescription'})
      5     for x in table:
----> 6         print(x.find('p').text)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Can someone tell me why it didn't work and how to make it right? I am using Python 3 and bs4. Thank you!

Comment: your `x.find('p')` is returning a blank/None , hence the error. just add a `if x.find('p')` before print

Comment: Thank you @Shijith! I added what you suggested but the code stopped without printing all the descriptions for all the links in list. No error though. Wonder what it's missing?

Comment: table = soup.select('.templatetext') should get you all the text for job description. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the [webpage](https://www.seek.co.nz/data-analyst-jobs/full-time?daterange=31&salaryrange=70000-999999&salarytype=annual), it is clear that the first two posts that you'll get through `soup.find_all('a', attrs={'data-automation': 'jobTitle'}, href=True)` are advertisements or promoted posts, and consequently the webpages these [two](https://www.seek.co.nz/job/40942929?type=promoted#searchRequestToken=10da5bac-c9c3-4037-b71b-e0018cd3ab76) and the [other job postings](https://www.seek.co.nz/job/40942450?type=standout#searchRequestToken=10da5bac-c9c3-4037-b71b-e0018cd3ab76) lead to are different. For the latter, perhaps `soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'templatetext'})` will do the job.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I need to make it work for all the posts. Just tried this but didn't work. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `find_all`

```
for link in link_list:
    response = requests.get(link, 'lxml')
    sp = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    table = sp.find_all('div',attrs={'data-automation': 'jobDescription'})
    for x in table:
        all_p = x.find_all('p')
        for para in all_p:
            if para:
                print(para.text)
```